# Howto generate a Yocto image with spanish full-support by default

Tags: keyboard, settings, locale, yocto

I'm having troubles trying to setup a Yocto image with full support to
English and Spanish languages (Spanish as default). The image I am building is based on the rocko branch, and my distro is "systemd" based.

My current distro.conf yocto setup is this:

```
GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES ?= "es_ES.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8"
IMAGE_LINGUAS ?= "es-es en-us"
```

With this setup I am getting an image with this locale settings:

```
# locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

# localectl
System Locale: n/a
   VC Keymap: ES
  X11 Layout: es
   X11 Model: pc105
 X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp

# locale -a
C
POSIX
en_US
es_ES

# locale -m
ES

# locale charmap
ANSI_X3.4-1968

# rpm -qa | grep charmap
glibc-charmap-es-2.26-r0.corei7_64
```

The image built with that setup doesn't work as expected. When I press Ñ
(enye) key on the ssh console, I get this:

```
root at hostname:~#
(arg: 1)
```

As you can see, 'ñ' character is not printed on the console.

After a lot of tests, I have been able to fix this creating these two files:

```
$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es:en

$ cat /etc/profile.d/locale.sh
LC_ALL=es_ES
LANG=es_ES
LANGUAGE=es_ES
```

After rebooting, I get this localectl settings:

```
# localectl
System Locale: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
              LANGUAGE=es:en
   VC Keymap: ES
  X11 Layout: es
   X11 Model: pc105
 X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

And the 'Ñ' key works as expected:

```
root at hostname:~# ñññññ
```

I don't know how to fix this issue without having to make manual changes to the generated image. I would like the generated image with Spanish support available once the .wic image is burned into my USB memory stick.

Is that posible? How should be managed?

Thanks in advance for your time! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I solved my issue. First of all, create this files:

```
$ cat locale.conf
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es

$ cat locale.sh
LANG=es_ES

$ cat vconsole.conf
KEYMAP=es
```

After that, create this recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Add es language support"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SRC_URI = " \
    file://locale.conf \
    file://vconsole.conf \
    file://locale.sh"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
do_install(){
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/profile.d/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/locale.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/vconsole.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/locale.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/profile.d/
}
FILES_${PN} ="${sysconfdir}/*"
```

Hope this answer will help in the future somebody else!  :-)

Comment: Just a little note: add `export` at `locale.sh` to the variable definition. On my end, without "export" it didn't worked. This: `export LANG=es` works.

Answer (score 1):

Create a recipe(.bb) file and recompile again.

go to your `meta-layer/recipes-core/`

**vi hello.bb**

```
DESCRIPTION= "added language support"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
LICENSED="CLOSED"
SRC_URI = "file://locale.conf \
           file://locale.sh"
S="${WORKDIR}"
do_install(){
 install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/profile.d/
 install -m 0777 ${S}/locale.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}
 install -m 0777 ${S}/locale.sh ${D}${syscondif}/profile.d/
}
FILES_${PN} ="${sysconfdir}/*"
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful Mr. Siva and first of all I want to thank you so much for your time. It has some typos I will fix in the next anwer. However, the key issue was to solve this issue without making manual changes, and  adding two manually generated files is a "manual change" for me. I hope there is a better way to solve this without doing this.